# Custom join in Dataprep

Tags: join, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

Can I join two tables using custom condition rather than equal?
Eg, I have two tables in **BigQuery**. Table A has 3 columns `start_range`, `end_range` and `grade`. Table B has data coming from **Storage** using cloud functions and has a particular column **"marks"**. I am creating a flow in **DataPrep** such that join these tables which should satisfy the condition:

```
SELECT data.grade FROM  data  INNER JOIN student_data ON student_data.marks BETWEEN data.start_range AND data.end_range
```

and then paste the data to a new table. But I could not find any provision for custom condition. Only two columns can be matched for join. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best chance would be to implement your solution in BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  grade, marks
FROM
  `project.dataset.student_data` a
JOIN
  `project.dataset.data` b
ON
  a.marks > b.start_range AND a.marks < b.end_range
```

If you insist on Dataprep, I don't believe there's any way to join on a range. If I understood your case correctly, what you have is something like this:

[image]
[image]

...and you want to get As and Bs instead of the integer marks in `student_data`. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but you can use a new formula with a case, something like this:

```
  CASE([(marks >= 0) && (marks < 50),
    'D',
    (marks >= 50) && (marks < 100),
    'C',
    (marks >= 100) && (marks < 150),
    'B',
    (marks >= 150) && (marks <= 200),
    'A'])
```

You'd just need to click "New step" on the recipe, chose "New formula" and then add it under "Formula". It should look like so:
[image]

Then you can even use "Lookup" to join any other useful data you might have in the `data` table using "grade" as the lookup key.

Comment: But grade and marks are different, right? For example `grade` is in string like "A", "B+", etc whereas `marks` in integer like 100,85,72 etc. So how can be both considered as join keys?

Comment: Ok, I think I see how I missed your point, I'm going to edit my answer now.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks like a switch case right? But if there are number of ranges like more than 20-25, you are saying that all conditions should  be included in the CASE statements?

Comment: Let us assume there are more than 100 ranges! So what will you do? All "CASE"s cannot be written right?

Comment: @DeviOS I added an alternative solution in BigQuery.